# lighter way for inter-thread communication than performSelector:onThread:withObject

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, real-time, nsthread

I was testing [performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelector%3aonThread%3awithObject%3awaitUntilDone%3a) for inter-thread communication as recommended by Matt Ghallagher's [tutorial](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/08/safe-threaded-design-and-inter-thread.html). Turns out that it is *extremely* slow, and pretty much [no good](http://www.rossbencina.com/code/real-time-audio-programming-101-time-waits-for-nothing) for real time audio applications. Any suggestions?

Comment: GCD is good for multithreading.

Comment: Hi, if you didn't target iOS. You can write your own inter-thread communication by using NSPort and NSPortMessage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the main thread:

```
AnyClass myObject;

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
   // do asynchronous work
   // environment objects and variables will be available
   [myObject doSomething];
});
```

It really does not get any simpler than that...

Comment: I'm not sure how this addresses my question. I'm talking about a specific thread asking for a method to be executed on another specific thread and sending it a parameter.. in your case you are just asking myobject to do something on another randomly generated thread.. or am i wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "randomly generated"? I recommend reading up on GCD, as it will reduce the amount of code you use dramatically. You can specify your own created queue (instead of the global queue) as well, but in many cases this is not necessary by design.